# C# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax in .cshtml fails to send data to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a .cshtml page which builds an array of data which looks like this in the console.log:

```
JSON.stringify(obj) = [{"ParcelKey":8911,"ParcelStatus":"Check"},{"ParcelKey":8912,"ParcelStatus":"Check"}]
```

I have Ajax code which looks like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method  
    url: "/Parcel/BulkParcelStatusUpdateSave", // Controller/Action   
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    traditional: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
              const myArray = data.split("|")
              $('#Parcel_Save_Success').removeClass('hidden');
              $('#CaseStatus').val(myArray[0]);
              $("#DetailedParcelGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Error While Saving Parcel Details. Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }

});
```

I have a model which looks like this:

```
public class ParcelBulkUpdateSaveModel
{
    public int ParcelKey { get; set; }
    public string ParcelStatus { get; set; }

}
```

And in the ParcelController, I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public string BuldParcelStatusUpdateSave(List<ParcelBulkUpdateSaveModel> sentData)
{
    string returnString = "";

    foreach (var record in sentData)
    {
        _repo.BulkParcelStatusUpdateSave(record);
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

I have a breakpoint set on the foreach statement in the controller.

When I run the application, the Ajax executes the error and I get the 2 alerts.

Why is the Ajax call not able to connect to the controller?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Is it failing to send the object to the server, or is it failing to make the request to the server at all?  The question seems vague between the two.  What is the actual error?  In your browser's debugging tools, what is the response from the server?

Comment: Don't know if it's just a typo here on SO, but you have BuldParcel... for the control method, but your ajax code is going to BulkParcel...
If that's not the issue, what do your alerts say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

Your calling `BulkParcelStatusUpdateSave` 
when the function is `BuldParcelStatusUpdateSave`